# Android Studio java compiler error， java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.print.PrinterCapabilitiesInfo$Builder.lambda$setColorModes

Tags: android

when I work my android project on Android Studio with java 1.8, An error occurred.

```
 Caused by: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: 
android.print.PrinterCapabilitiesInfo$Builder.lambda$setColorModes$89(int)void/invokeStatic
```

At first I think it might be something wrong with IDE or **Java environment**, so I changed computer to do this. But the error shows up again.
Anyone know how to deal with it?